# How to compare DB result with JSON if JDBC query is returning multiple rows and data is available in JSON in the form of array

Tags: jmeter

Below is the table: 
FirstName      LastName      Email 
James         Thomas     james@gmail.com 
Teresa         Smith       Teresa@gmail.com 
Kristina        Joseph      Kristina@gmail.com

Below is the JSON in the form of array 
Personal Details [
{ 
FirstName: James 
LastName:Thomas 
Email: james@gmail.com  
} 
{ 
FirstName: Teresa 
LastName: Smith 
Email: Teresa@gmail.com 
}

{ 
FirstName: Kristina 
LastName: Joseph 
Email: Kristina@gmail.com 
} ]

In My JDBC request query result I am getting 3 rows. 
 In JMeter how can I validate: 
Row 1 from DB with PersonalDetails[0].FirstName, PersonalDetails[0].LastName and PersonalDetails[0].Email from JSON 
Row 2 from DB with PersonalDetails[1].FirstName, PersonalDetails[1].LastName and PersonalDetails[1].Email from JSON 
Row 3 from DB with PersonalDetails[2].FirstName, PersonalDetails[2].LastName and PersonalDetails[2].Email from JSON

Answer (score 1):

If you specify the "Variable Names" in the [JDBC Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JDBC_Request) sampler like:

[image]

you will get the following [JMeter Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html):

```
FirstName_1=James
FirstName_2=Teresa
FirstName_3=Kristina
FirstName_#=3
LastName_1=Thomas
etc.
```

Then you can add a [JSR223 Assertion](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/scripting-jmeter-assertions-in-groovy-a-tutorial) to the request which returns the JSON and put the following code into "Script" area:

```
def json = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parse(prev.getResponseData())

json.eachWithIndex { entry, index ->
    if (entry.get('FirstName') != vars.get('FirstName_' + (index + 1))) {
        AssertionResult.setFailure(true)
        AssertionResult.setFailureMessage('First name mismatch')
    }
    if (entry.get('LastName') != vars.get('LastName_' + (index + 1))) {
        AssertionResult.setFailure(true)
        AssertionResult.setFailureMessage('Last name mismatch')
    }
    if (entry.get('Email') != vars.get('Email_' + (index + 1))) {
        AssertionResult.setFailure(true)
        AssertionResult.setFailureMessage('Email name mismatch')
    }
}
```